# How to call a method inside a python script obfuscated

Tags: python, python-3.x, obfuscation, pyarmor

Any idea how I can call a method from a REST API using Python 3.11, this method is an entry point function to a python script. The python script is obfuscated with PyArmor 8. Is it possible to call a specific method inside an obfuscated class? Are there any other Obfuscation tools apart from PyArmor which can help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail? It is clearly possible to call an obfuscated method as if it was not possible then the point of obfuscation would be moot.

Comment: @JonSG But when I obfuscate a python script with pyarmor, I'm not able to import any function inside it. Do you have any examples where you are importing a method from the obfuscated script inside another python program?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could call your methods and classes normally, as if as not obfuscated, in runtime.

However, only in runtime, because pyarmor descaphy scripts in running. Im other worlds, you cannot get this methods by IDE/TXT. But theys will access for another modules runtime.

Except if you used "private" as parameter no pyarmor when ofuscate your script.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).